# start debugging a fresh flutter project not working

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

Thanks in Advance for Taking the Time to read through my question

I'm new to **Flutter**, I'm trying to start a project following the instructions of the documentation

I've done the set up correctly but when ever I try to Run the app in **VScode** i get this error!

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.1.2/gradle-7.1.2.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.1.2/gradle-7.1.2.pom
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

I did Search for a solution but I had no luck finding a fix to my problem!

Please help!

Comment: Maybe Google is restricted in your country, use VPN from other countries.

Comment: @amir_a14 , Thank you dear sir for your suggestion i will try to use a VPN and then come back to you with feedback ^_^

Comment: @amir_a14 what you suggested dear sir did the trick. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as MR.amir_a14 suggested, unfortunately the cause of my Problem was being located in a Google restricted country, using a VPN solved My Problem !

Thank you MR.amir_a14 .